# If you stop time, does your body losing heat burn everything to ashes?

Tags: science-based

If time is stopped but you still move it means that now your movements are happening at infinite speed.

Even your breathing infinitely fast.

And also your metabolism which means that you are dissipating an infinite amount of energy, heat in the universe.

By this logic, would stopping time turn yourself into a bomb, into the new big bang creating a new universe with infinite energy?

Comment: Where do you get an infinite amount of food to supply this energy? Presumably you'd be dead infinitley fast and cease to metabolise. It's a difficult question to answer without precise knowledge of the physics you're using as a model, it also seems to lack any worldbuilding aspect. Please take our [tour] and read-up in our [help] about how we work, welcome to worldbuilding.

Comment: @Draft85 the energy innsinde you is not infinite but you are moving at speed 1 and the universe is moving at speed 0...between 0 and 1 there's infinite.

Comment: Energy is not power. You are talking about power.

Comment: I think you mean a finite set comprising the sum of an infinite number of infinitessimals, bit of a different thing.

Comment: There's no infinite energy being released by your body even if everything stopped. Just because you're still functioning at normal speed while the rest of the universe is stopped, all that'd probably happen would be the energy you produced in your relative time (say, in the ~30 seconds you have before suffocating) would suddenly be emitted at once. Think 30 bombs of 10 mg worth of tnt being released as one bomb worth 0,3 grams of tnt.

Comment: The intro "If time is stopped but you still move it means that..." needs a lot more definition. Exactly how are you still able to move? Are we somehow talking about different universes juxtaposed on each other? You certainly can not move in a universe when time is zero - too many divide-by-zero contradictions. That's why nothing can travel at cee. There is no distance that you can travel.

Comment: Now, if time just went exceedingly SLOW, but not non-zero, now you are into calculus and limits.

Comment: if time is stopped all interactions stops, something with time cannot effect something without, and vice versa. you can't move because air molecules can't get out of your way. things without time cannot be heated, cooled, nor illuminated. your person cannot move, cannot see, cannot hear, because the stuff around them is not experiencing time.

Comment: @user84882 infinities are often misleading. Yes you can theoretically push with infinite force, but at the same time it takes infinitely long before the particles you push against to actually react. This means that if you expend 10 newtons of force on a bowlingball while you are timestopped that when time resumes, 10 Newtons of force are added to the Bowlingball rather than it turning into an infinite energy source.

Comment: if you're going fast enough for time to be actually stopped then you'll no longer have any mass because of the amount of energy in you. why not just make it be almost the speed of light? its effectively frozen that way without completely destroying you and everything around you

Answer (score 4):

If it really is just you moving faster, you would die from suffocation by breathing all the oxygen around you without enough more oxygen flowing in to replace it. Trying to move to another location with more oxygen would also kill you due to the pressure waves caused by movement (as would the motions due to breathing).

A better (or more interesting) way to frame this is if you enter a pocket of time that is faster than everything immediately around you. I assume you're talking about how the heat you radiate gets trapped at the boundary and accumulates. Though, the question is where does the air you breathe come from? Larger the pocket the more air you have to breathe but the longer it takes to accumulate heat. Similarly, your infinite energy thing doesn't make sense, but it is unnecessary since the accumulation of thermal energy is what matters and whether enough energy and oxygen are present to cause ignition in the pocket.

I lean towards no. You definitely don't have infinite energy available so definitely no big bang, and you would run out of oxygen in your pocket to stay alive which is required for your metabolism to produce more waste heat, which simultaneously also reduces the oxygen available for ignition.

By the way, the same mechanism that keeps thermal energy from leaving at the boundary also also keeps CO2 from getting out. Not good. But even worse is how the same thing might result in everything that enters the time bubble might not be able to get back out resulting in a pressure increase so after enough translation movement, if the increased pressure has not yet caused you to suffocate or have cardiac arrest, you would flash ignite so maybe you would still burn to a crisp.

The boundary rules are weird. Does something get left behind when you and your bubble move away? Or does it stay trapped? If it's trapped you get what I described above.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a fictional world in which time can be stopped while certain individuals can still move around (ala the 2002 film [ClockStoppers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clockstoppers)) then the rules are largely up to you.

If you are trying to imagine a realistic world, you will have very many problems such as:

- All electromagnetic radiation would be frozen in place, so you
  wouldn't be able to see anything while standing still.
- Gravitational waves would also be frozen, so you wouldn't experience gravity
- If atoms are "frozen" and can't interact with you, moving will be very difficult since there's no frictional forces to push you forward when you step or push on things.
- If atoms can interact with you, then walking around will create vacuum behind you and immense pressures ahead of you, and probably cause a fusion "event" (ala [XKCD's Relativistic Baseball](https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/))

The amount of energy you radiate away would be dependent on how "long" you stayed in one place in your frozen universe. Your metabolism requires oxygen to continue functioning, and there's no more gas diffusion. So it brings up some interesting questions about how the boundary between unfrozen "you" and the frozen universe is defined.

TLDR - You would either suffocate because the world is frozen and you can't breath, or you'd move and blow everything up when time resumed.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with abestrange: I think you are bordering on such a hypothetical here that you can make up your own rules for worldbuilding. Don't forget: time and space are (supposedly) inescapably linked so, in theory, if time stopped, so should any notion of physical space. In other words, you COUDLN'T be conscious to perceive stopped time. Unless of course you believe consciousness stands outside of time. Maybe you could take some kind of mystical approach to circumvent the seeming physics violation here...?

Found this article. Might help you:

https://futurism.com/the-physics-of-stopping-time-2

Answer (score 1):

**Fallacies**

There are a few problems with the proposed outcome of infinite energy. I'll focus solely on that and not on additional problems that might be experienced.

Take a picture and you'll see everything is stationary. Without time there is no movement. That means you would be stuck between the molecules, frozen in time nearly as much as the rest of the world. Your last breath literally stuck in your throat. I don't know if you can give potential energy to anything in 0% time, but let's give it the benefit of a doubt and say you can.

An example. Ignoring breathing difficulties, in a 50% speed time while you are 100% speed is much like you are using pulleys to interact with everything. That is from the 50% point of view. You're ***not*** stronger. Every second you give off the same energy, but as the others go 50% speed you can give off double that power in the same time. This is a *potential* energy. That is, if you push a second, they can push half a second.

That means the slower the time goes, the more time you have the opportunity to put in the same energy. That means if you push an object in 1% speed you'll basically be able to push 100 times longer against the same object that someone inside the 1% speed zone.

Now for your problem. The idea is that pushing against objects in 0% time will give you infinite energy. Unfortunately that will not be the case. It means that, potentially, you could push an infinite amount of time against something. The problem is that you then need to do it. In the above examples you can only give off the energy of a second if you put a second effort into it. If you have 0.00000000000001% time, you can start pushing a 1 ton concrete slab, but you will still need to push some time against it to get enough energy into it. *All actions cost the same amount of energy*.

Let's go back to 0% time. Now push until you've put in 100 joule. It isn't infinite, you only impart that you imparted. A seconds work is your seconds work, regardless of the timeframe of anything else.

**Conclusion**

I've ignored a lot of physical problems you would have with differing timespeeds to illustrate the point. A time stop would not equal infinite energy. All actions cost the same amount of energy, but you have more time to put the energy in if you interact with a slow time object. If you interact with an object without time, a push against it is still only a push. If you want it to be infinite, you need to push infinitely.

Comment: Yes! Time might "stand still", you still need to generate the energy to push the molecules aside. If the rest of the universe is time-stopped it'll TAKE infinite energy to push them aside... while you have a finite energy output, despite that finite energy output being essentially infinite in the timeframe. An example of how this works: you can divide 1 into infinite smaller pieces, but if you add those infinite small pieces together the maximum you can add together is 1 despite there being infinite pieces to put together.

Answer (score 0):

If you can stop time, but still move, then you are already breaking *so many* of the fundamental laws of existence that you really should not worry about the heat balance.

That's like worrying if your breath needs a mint, when you get arrested for genocide.

If your story must include time stoppage, yet still allow movement and action without time, then you are using so much handwaving that you might as well go the Full Monty and enjoy the experience without worrying about the trivia.